# How do I access the "grade category" in Google Classroom using their API

Tags: python, google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to build a dashboard to monitor class grades using the Google Classroom API.

When I create an assignment through the website, I have the option to give it a "Grade Category" which affects how it is weighted in the final grade. For example, I can create (in Course Settings) a Homework category that counts 20% toward the final grade or a Quizzes category that counts 30% toward the final grade and so on.

I've been using the python API and can download most everything I need so far *except* this "Grade Category", which means I can't compute their grades in my dashboard or do things like drop the lowest grade or similar actions. I figured there would be a field like "gradeCategory" but I can't find it anywhere.

Anyone else run across this?

Answer (score 1):

- Use the method [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/get) to retrieve grades
- Use 
  [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch) to assign / modify grades
- For the latter you need to specify `updateMask` either as `draftGrade` or
  `assignedGrade` - depending on what grade you want to update.
- For both you need to specify `courseId`, `courseWorkId` and `id` (the submission identifier)
- To retrieve the corresponding Ids you can use the methods [Courses:list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list), [courseWork:list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) and [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) respectively
- Have a look at the [studentSubmissions resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#StudentSubmission) for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for these links. This is all what I'm actually using right now, but none of this has the information about "Grade Category". I can retrieve what the grades are, but there's nothing in there about the "Category", nor what the course settings are for how grades are weighted for the final course grade.

Comment: Unfortunately this has not been implemented so far. There are several relevant feature requests, I suggest you to mark the [main one](https://issuetracker.google.com/123557207) with a "star" to increase visibility and hope for soon implementation.

Comment: I need this feature of Grade Category also ! Thanks for your question @MattBellis